# Get a type to rely on another type; type conditions

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `Test` component that must accept a `one` prop where the object must have an `a` field but only have an `id` field *if* the `two` prop is not provided. If the `two` prop is provided then the `one` prop's object must not have an `id` field.

How can this be achieved? The closest I could get is using this interface:

```
interface Test {
  one: {
    a: string;
    id?: number;
  };
  two?: number;
}
```

Obviously it will not work properly since the `id` field and `two` props are just set to optional rather than conditioning from each other.

Here is the demo I have built:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Test
        one={{
          a: 'valid example with id and no two prop',
          id: 5,
        }}
      />

      <Test
        one={{
          a: 'valid example with two prop and no id field',
        }}
        two={9}
      />

      <Test
        one={{
          a: 'should have id or two prop; needs to error',
        }}
      />

      <Test
        one={{
          a: 'cannot have both id field AND two prop; needs to error',
          id: 2,
        }}
        two={5}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

interface Test {
  one: {
    a: string;
    id?: number;
  };
  two?: number;
}

const Test = ({ one, two }: Test): JSX.Element => {
  return <p>test</p>;
};
```

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-2wsnwj?file=App.tsx

I wondered whether I could write the types like this, but apparently not:

```
type One = {
  a: string
  id?: number
}

type Two = One.id ? number : null
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you

***UPDATE:***

I have just realised that the answer I accepted is wrong as it still expects prop `two` all the time, hence the error in two of the components in this demo (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-owrj8a?file=App.tsx).

I tried to change it from the answer to this:

```
interface A {
  a: string;
}
interface OptionOne {
  one: A & {
    id: number;
  };
  two: never;
}
interface OptionTwo {
  one: A;
  two: number;
}
type FinalType = OptionOne | OptionTwo;

// type Test =
//   | { one: { a: string; id: number } }
//   | { one: { a: string }; two: number };

const Test = ({ one, two }: FinalType): JSX.Element => {
  return <p>test</p>;
};
```

But it has the same effect. Does anyone know a fix for this?

The error if prop `two` is not provided:

```
Type '{ one: { a: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FinalType'.
  Property 'two' is missing in type '{ one: { a: string; }; }' but required in type 'OptionTwo'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make `Test` a union type which covers all acceptable states:

```
type Test = {one: {a: string; id: number}} | 
            {one: {a:string}; two:number}
```

Edit after OP's comment:

The issue you are facing now is not anything strange. TypeScript doesn't let you destructure `two` from `props` because you have told that in some scenarios that property doesn't exist.

What you can do in such situations, manually check if the `two` field exists, an if it does, use it.

```
 const Test = (props: FinalType): JSX.Element => {
  if ('two' in props) {
    return <p>{props.two}</p>;
  }
  return <p>test</p>;
};
```

The errors are gone now.

Comment: I have just realised that this answer does not work as the component errors if prop `two` is not provided. Do you or anyone know a fix for this? I've updated my question and added a new demo

Comment: I appreciate the update, thanks, although an error is still showing with your solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x4eoz5?file=App.tsx - also, wouldn't your solution be less performant as it requires an if statement and potentially returns something unwanted?

Comment: @user8758206 That error is caused because you are not providing neither the 'two' prop nor the 'id' field. Also, If you don't want if statements, you will need to change the structure of the app.

Comment: yep, silly me - I didn't notice that! You're right and it works now :)